# where is Android NDK printf output?

Tags: android, c++, c, android-ndk

I have following code c++ code:

```
static void print_string(JNIEnv * env, jclass clazz, jstring str){
    jboolean isCopy;
    const char* utf_string;
    utf_string = env->GetStringUTFChars(str, &isCopy);

    env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(str, utf_string);
    //LOGI("%s",utf_string);
  //  LOGE("JNI Out = %s", utf_string);
    printf("jni out: %s",utf_string);
   __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "MyTag", "The value is %s", utf_string);
    env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(str, utf_string);
}
```

I don't see any output in logcat. So where does it goes? How can I see it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Accordint to [the docs](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-log.html#viewingStd) the output is lost:

> By default, the Android system sends `stdout` and `stderr` (`System.out` and `System.err`) output to `/dev/null`.

There are methods to change that (on rooted devices), for example using `setprop`, taken from the docs:

```
$ adb shell stop
$ adb shell setprop log.redirect-stdio true
$ adb shell start
```